# Accessing specific version of Java in Safari

Tags: safari, java, mojave, plugins

I am using Safari 12 running on macOS Mojave 10.14. The Web based VM detects the installed version of Java on my Mac as 1.5. For my particular needs version 1.6 is required.

I have installed the latest JRE 1.8. I also tried to install the JDK 11 (could not find only the JRE).

At the moment, on my Mac, I have Java 1.6, 1.8 and 11 in the folder `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`.

At the same time, I have a JavaAppletPlugin installed in `/Library/Internet Plug-ins/` folder, but I don't know from which version.

In System Preferences, I have the Java item, but there is no option to add multiple paths to Java, like it used to be before, and only Java 1.8 seems to be recognized.

How do I tell Safari to use a more recent version of Java?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Kindly [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/341194/edit) the question and specify how you installed the various versions of Java. Specify any command lines or download links. Also mention the website which you are visiting in Safari to check the version of Java.